# Communities forgot password emails?

Tags: community, forgot-your-password

This is more of a question for everyone but I have two clients running communities and both are having issues where the forgot password email is just not sending anything?

I checked the template setting in communities settings and it was set to a template that doesnt exist... I thought that was is but i created a simple text based forgot your password email and set it to that and its still not sending anything?

Any ideas?

Comment: I have a ticket open with salesforce investigating whats going on

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hey everyone so i finally got salesforce support to help me figure this out.

Turns out with the winter 14 release they changed the way forgot your password emails work for communities.  Instead of sending a username and password in the email they now send a special link that allows people to click and change their password.

The trick is that your forgot your password email template needs to include this special merge field (which of course is not documented anywhere)

```
{!Community_Url}
```

if you include that it will be replace with a special url that allows the user to change their password and logs them in.

Its actually a much better solution the problem was they didnt tell anyone to update their templates and i still cant find it documented anywhere.