# Community Forgot Password Link "Insufficient Access"

Tags: community

I have a Community where I want to direct users to a custom VF page so they can reset their password (I've disabled the Custom VF Page) to confirm why this might be happening.

I generate the link with `{!Community_Url}` as specified in the template e-mails that are created and here: [Communities forgot password emails?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17887/communities-forgot-password-emails)

When I follow the link in another Sandbox using the same configuration I'm able to change the user's password, however, after deploying to another sandbox, when I open the link I get:

```
Insufficient Privileges
You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary.
```

Again, I've disabled the custom VF page in the community manager, the link opens the: `/secur/forgotpassword.jsp?token` URL relative to my sandbox.

*Update*

I've noticed that clicking: "Reset Password" From the admin console sends a link that works.

In my page I'm using the typical method to reset the password:

```
boolean success = Site.forgotPassword(username);
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be the know bug in the Winter 15 release (https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000IWbfAAG).  If you have a "My Domain".  Scheduled fix in next release. I have personally opened a ticket with Salesforce as we cannot wait that long for our large community to have the ability to reset their own passwords again.